# Finding the closest point in a set to another point in n-dimensional space: efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm a programmer and am working on writing an efficient algorithm that, given a point `P` in n-dimensional space, can find the closest point from a set of points. For my problem, each of the `n` axis in the n-dimensional is constrained by `a>=0` and `a<=100`, where `a` is the axis. There are `n` points in the set, each one placed at 100 on one axis and 0 on all of the others. For example, if n=7 (7-dimentional), this is the set of points:

```
set = {(100,0,0,0,0,0,0), (0,100,0,0,0,0,0), (0,0,100,0,0,0,0), (0,0,0,100,0,0,0), (0,0,0,0,100,0,0), (0,0,0,0,0,100,0), (0,0,0,0,0,0,100)}
```

For the purpose of example, let's say the given point is: `P = (0,91,16,0,0,70,0)`

I need to find the point in `set` that is closest to `P`. Of course, I could use n-dimensional Euclidean distance formula between `P` and each point in `set`, however as a programmer, I'm very concerned with efficiency.

Here's my hypothesis:

$\forall a \in P, if a=0  \bigwedge set[positionOf(a)][positionOf(a)]=100,$ then $set[positionOf(a)]$ is **not** the closest point to $P$.

Note: $positionOf(x)$ means the index of $x$ in the parent array and $array[x]$ means the element in $array$ at position (index) $x$. Also note, in order for this to work, `set` must be ordered how it is above.

In other words: let's say there's a zero at position 4 in our `P` (like in our example: (0,91,16,0,**0**,70,0)), then the point within `set` where the number at position 4 equals 100 (and all other numbers are zero) cannot be the closest point to `P`.

I realize that `P` **cannot** equal the origin (all zeros) in order for this hypothesis to hold up. How could I proved this? Does this hold true for all cases?

Sorry if I did not explain well, I realize it's rather abstract. In my actual algorithm, there are many more dimensions than 7, and many of the numbers within the coordinates are equal to zero—thus I could eliminate them from my computation if this hypothesis is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct (except at the origin). I doubt, in general, that this will drastically improve your algorithm's efficiency, though. I could be wrong...

Here's an improved algorithm:

Let $i$ be the index for which $P_i$ is maximal. Then $e_i$ (the $i$th vector in your set, ordered the way you wrote it) is the closest point.

Proof: Compute the euclidean distance, take a derivative or two, and you're done.

There. That's linear time in the number of dimensions. Better than the $O(n^2)$ needed to compute all the Euclidean distances.

By the way, this all assumes that the query-point $P$ also satisfies $0 \le p_i \le 100$ for all $i$, the same way the points in your "set" do. I wasn't quite able to parse your question in a way that made me sure that this was what you were asking.

Comment: That constraint doesn't really matter. What you're choosing is the $i$ such that $\lvert p_i-100\rvert$ is minimal.

Comment: @John Thanks a lot for the reply! It took me a little while, but I understand now. I just have one question, what happens when $P$ does not have a maximal value? (e.g. there are multiple values that are maximal) Would the best approach in this case be to just use Euclidean distance formula to find the closest of the maximal values?

Comment: Suppose that $P$ is $(40, 40, 10, 0, 40)$. Then $P$ is *equally close* to $e_1, e_2$, and $e_5$; you can check this out using the Euclidean distance formula in this case -- for all three distances, the squared distance is $(40-100)^2 + 40^2 + 10^2 + 40^2$, although with the three terms involving "40" in various different positions.